# Im not sure how i can make my program sort and read from an external file

Tags: python, list, file, sorting, external

I am creating a dice game in a nut shell and the scores get saved to an external file name 'scores'

```
Krystian: 5
Adam: 7
Unknown: 2
AWD: 18
Muaadh: 5
Yasir: 6
Zaim: 7
Ishfaq: 5
Tanzeel: 87
Hamzah: 3
Mohammed: 5
Robert: 6
Yasir: 5
Krystian: 61
Natalie: 72
```

and these are the usernames and their scores. I have seen some csv sort algorithms but the problem is that i am only a beginner and i don't have a clue on how they work so i can't really use them. What im really looking for is an explanation of how to sort them from highest score down to the lowest score and i want the program to print out the top 5 players.

```
with open('scores.txt', newline='') as f:
   data = [{k: v for k, v in row.items()} for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=':', fieldnames=['name', 'score'], quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)]

   sorted_data = sorted(data, key = lambda i: i['score'], reverse=True)
   for x in sorted_data:
       print (x['name'] + ': ' + x['score'])
```

so far that is all i have managed to 'copy' from other posts but it still doesn't work properly. I think it's worth sharing that when u run the program it asks the user for their name, then it gets their score then it saves to the file and at the very end is where i ask the user if they would like to see top 5 players , so that is where i want my program to sort the external file and print out the top 5 players.
I do apologise as i have seen many posts like this but the only reason i post this myself is because i really don't understand any of them. Thanks for making it this far.

Comment: Why not just save the results in a pickled dictionary? You can eliminate the need for the csv reader entirely.

Comment: @RobertKearns not sure what a pickled dictionary is and i only mentioned csv since i saw it on another similiar post meaning it doesn't have to have csv.

Comment: Oh okay, well how are these results stored when the program is running? Meaning before you write them to a csv.

Comment: @RobertKearns so basically i have the player do their run of the game . Then i have f=open("scores.txt","a+")   
    f.write('\n%s: %d' % (name2 , total2))
    f.close() in order to save the score to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got it 80% of the way, you just need to isolate the top 5 scores, get rid of the leading white spaces, and convert the strings to integers. I would recommend using a dictionary instead of a csv file, but what you have is working. You also have duplicates in your csv, which using a dictionary would fix.

```py
with open('scores.txt', newline='') as f:
            # Stripping the leading spaces off of the numbers and names
   data = [{k.strip(): v.strip() for k, v in row.items()} for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=':', fieldnames=['name', 'score'], quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)]

                                              # Making the string an integer
   sorted_data = sorted(data, key = lambda i: int(i['score']), reverse=True)
                       # Isolating the top 5 results using indexes.
   for x in sorted_data[:5]:
       print (x['name'] + ': ' + x['score'])
```

Comment: Hey , i test ran the program and it seems to have worked just fine. Thanks again for the solution and your time, appreciate the support. Hope you have a fantastic day!

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your problems is using a dictionary, which is non-sequential and doesn't support sorts.  You can instead make a list of every name, score pair in your file.  Just put the score first, and then you can call sorted on this list:

```
highscores = []

with open('scores.txt') as file_object:
  for line in file_object:
    name, score = line.rstrip().split(':')
    highscores.append ([int(score), name]) 

sorted_scores = sorted(highscores)
```

Then if you want to print out the scores:

```
for score, name in sorted_scores:
  print (name + ': ' + str(score))
```

Comment: The main data structure is actually a list of dictionaries, which can be easily sorted via the key argument.

Comment: Ahhh, right.  Is there a reason my code wouldn't work though?

Comment: Hey, i have tried to test run my program with this bit of code and it would appear it does not work as it suppose to work and is printing the list like 10 times in the wrong order. It might be my fault but either way thanks for your attempt and time appreciate it!

Comment: Well, I guess that answers my question!  Thanks for the update.